# jQuery :checked getting value of last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason even if i set the `checked` attribute to the radio button my jQuery code always defaults to the last button in the list why is that?

**HTML**

```
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=1 checked>one
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=2>two
```

**jQuery**

```
var dropResult;
$(function (){
    $(".t").click(function(){
        dropResult = $("input[name=drop]:checked").val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Try this - $("input[type='radio'].t:checked").val();

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I try it, `dropResult` is always the value of the checked box. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/zrznppvb/

Comment: Yeah i just realized that just now it was a big head scratchier lol. Needed to walk away from the computer then come back to see what was really going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so it seems i was losing my mind i didn't give `dropresult` a defualt value. The checked attribute is purely aesthetic until the radio button is changed and the new value is updated to the variable. It's very strange you would think since there is no value that any code checking it for a value to use would break

**Fixed with**

```
var dropResult = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using radio buttons with the same `name`. Radio buttons with the same name can only have **one** checked at a time.

It seems when multiple radio buttons with the same name are checked, the actual one checked defaults to the last one

So when you use `:checked`, it will only apply to the one that is actually selected(in this case the last one)

```js
console.log($(':checked').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=1 checked>one
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=2 checked>two
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=3 checked>three
```

Comment: But the `:checked` attribute only applies to the one that's selected.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine try this

```js
var dropResult;
$(function (){
    $(".t").click(function(){
        dropResult = $("input[name=drop]:checked").val();
      alert(dropResult);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=1 checked>one
<input class=t type=radio name=drop value=2>two
```